# How to create proto file to get byte array?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microservices, grpc, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using `GRPC` for sending data between `Microservices`.

I create a `proto` file like this:

```
service Selfie {
    rpc AddSelfie(SelfieRequest) returns (SelfieResponse);
}

message SelfieRequest{
    string OwnerId = 1;
    byte[] File = 2;
}

message SelfieResponse {
    bool Status=1;
    float Distance=2;
    string FileId=3;
}
```

When I Build my project, it has an error on `Byte[]`

> Selfie.proto(13, 9): Expected field name.

How can I fix it? thanks

Comment: Are you sure, that proto file supports an arrays?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, Its my question: (What Type I can use Instead of Byte[]). I use bytes instead of Byte[] and it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Protobuf not supported `byte[]`,We can use `bytes` instead of `byte[]`